# SQl Server datediff across rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have searched thoroughly and have not been able to find another post to show how to accomplish this. I am trying to find an easy way to calculate total hours clocked in between two dates. My table looks like this:

```
emp_num  | time                     | punch_type
399      | 2017-07-05 04:44:00.000  | 1
399      | 2017-07-05 14:30:00.000  | 2
399      | 2017-07-06 04:40:00.000  | 1
399      | 2017-07-06 13:31:00.000  | 2
```

punch_type indicates clock in =1 and clock out =2. I'd like to calculate the time difference between the two punches on the same day. Then SUM those total together to get total hours clocked in for 7/5 and 7/6.

EDIT: I forgot to mention sometimes there may be multiple punch in/outs per day.

Any ideas on how to accomplish?

Comment: Are there ever multiple sets of punches per day? Like lunch times?

Comment: yes just edited to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it

to find the work hours in each day

```
select emp_num,cast(time as date),datediff(hh,min(time),max(time))
from yourtable 
group by emp_num,cast(time as date)
```

to get the total hours for between x and y days

```
select emp_num,sum(tot_hours)
from 
(
select emp_num,cast(time as date),datediff(hh,min(time),max(time)) as tot_hours
from yourtable 
Where time >= '2017-07-05' and time < dateadd(dd,1,'2017-07-06')
group by emp_num,cast(time as date)
) a
Group by emp_num
```

**Note :** this considers there will be only two punches per day just like your sample data

Answer (score 0):

You can PIVOT your table to provide the correct layout for you

> PIVOT table documentation: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

You would want to PIVOT your table to have the following columns:

- Emp_num
- clock_in
- clock out
- Diff (now calculated as the datediff between the new clock-in and clock-out columns)

You can sum the last column by employee and date to get the answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE times
(
    emp_num    INT
  , [time]     DATETIME
  , punch_type TINYINT
);

INSERT INTO times
VALUES (399, '2017-07-05 04:44:00.000', 1)
     , (399, '2017-07-05 14:30:00.000', 2)
     , (399, '2017-07-06 04:40:00.000', 1)
     , (399, '2017-07-06 13:31:00.000', 2);

SELECT t1.emp_num
    , CAST(t1.time AS DATE) d
     , SUM(DATEDIFF(HOUR, t1.time, t2.time)) total_time
  FROM times t1
 OUTER APPLY
     (   SELECT TOP 1 t2.[time]
           FROM times t2
          WHERE t2.emp_num = t1.emp_num AND t2.punch_type = 2 AND t2.time > t1.time
          ORDER BY t2.time
     )       t2
 WHERE punch_type = 1
 GROUP BY t1.emp_num, CAST(t1.time AS DATE);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should give you the results you're looking for...

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TestData', 'U') IS NULL 
BEGIN   -- DROP TABLE #TestData;
    CREATE TABLE #TestData (
        emp_num INT NOT NULL,
        [time] DATETIME NOT NULL,
        punch_type TINYINT NOT NULL 
        );

    INSERT #TestData (emp_num, [time], punch_type) VALUES
        (399, '2017-07-05 04:44:00.000', 1),
        (399, '2017-07-05 14:30:00.000', 2),
        (399, '2017-07-06 04:40:00.000', 1),
        (399, '2017-07-06 13:31:00.000', 2);
END;

--==============================================================

WITH
    cte_AddRN AS (
        SELECT 
            td.emp_num, td.time, td.punch_type, 
            RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY td.emp_num, td.punch_type ORDER BY td.time)
        FROM
            #TestData td
        ),
    cte_PivotInOut AS (
        SELECT 
            arn.emp_num,
            PunchIn = MAX(CASE WHEN arn.punch_type = 1 THEN arn.time END),
            PunchOut = MAX(CASE WHEN arn.punch_type = 2 THEN arn.time END)
        FROM
            cte_AddRN arn
        GROUP BY
            arn.emp_num,
            arn.RN
        )
SELECT 
    pio.emp_num, 
    TotalHours = ROUND(SUM(DATEDIFF(ss, pio.PunchIn, pio.PunchOut) / 3600.0), 2)
FROM
    cte_PivotInOut pio
GROUP BY
    pio.emp_num;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, try this

```
SELECT a.[emp_num]                                    AS 'Employee Number',
              CAST(a.[Time] AS DATE)                  AS 'Time',                          
              DATEDIFF(hh , MIN(time), MAX(time))     AS 'Hours'
FROM dbo.times                                                                               AS a
GROUP BY a.[emp_num], CAST(a.[Time] AS DATE)
```